# Cleanup of Spark failed jobs staging directories on S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark job which writes data to AWS S3, sometimes the application fails and this leaves the spark staging directory behind on S3 as shown below.
[image]

My question is what is the best practices to automate the cleanup of these directories and how to achieve that?
Is there a Spark config to do so or there should be an independent step to perform the cleanup?